# How can I connect to kubernetes-dashboard via "https"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, kubernetes-dashboard

I have a running private Kubernetes Cluster (v1.20) with fargate instances for the pods on the complete cluster. Access is restricted to the nodePorts range and 443.
I use externalDns to create Route53 entries to route from my internal network to the Kubernetes cluster. Everything works fine with e.g. UIs listening on port 443.

So now I want to use the kubernetes-dashboard not via proxy to my localhost but via DNS resolution with Route53. For this, I made two changes in the kubernetes-dashboard.yml:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

is now:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: kubernetes-dashboard.hostname.local
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8443
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
```

and the container specs now contain the self-signed certificates:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          image: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.0.0
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8443
              protocol: TCP
          args:
            - --auto-generate-certificates
            - --namespace=kubernetes-dashboard
            - --tls-cert-file=/tls.crt
            - --tls-key-file=/tls.key
```

The certificates (the same used for the UIs) are mapped via kubernetes secret.

The subnets for the fargate instances are the same as for my other applications. Yet i receive a "Connection refused" when i try to call my dashboard.
Checking the dashboard with the localproxy the configuration setup seems fine. Also the DNS entry is resolved to the correct IP address of the fargate instance.

My problem here is, that I already use this setup and it works. But I see no difference to the dashboard here. Do I miss something?
Can anybody help me out here?

Greetings,
Eric